# How to remove the data object from the UI in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Am new to rails. After using the gem 'devise' along with 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' and 'devise-bootstrap-views', When I pass data from the controller to view

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

after the template, the data is shown again below it like json. Am not sure where that code is getting generated from.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">

      <h1>This where all the friends are displayed</h1>
      <h4>sally@gmail.com</h4>
      <h6>Joined 6 days ago</h6>

      <h4>sam@gmail.com</h4>
      <h6>Joined 6 days ago</h6>

    <!-- NOT SURE WHY THIS IS GETTING DISPLAYED -->
    [#&lt;User id: 1, email: &quot;sally@gmail.com&quot;, created_at: &quot;2016-07-29 14:47:33&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2016-08-04 09:36:00&quot;&gt;, #&lt;User id: 2, email: &quot;sam@gmail.com&quot;, created_at: &quot;2016-07-29 15:42:36&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2016-07-29 15:42:36&quot;&gt;]

    </div>
    <!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <footer>
    <p>&copy;App</p>
  </footer>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>This where all the friends are displayed</h1>
<%= @users.each do |user|  %>
  <h4><%= user.email %></h4>
  <h6>Joined <%= time_ago_in_words(user.created_at) %> ago</h6>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have u done any inspect kind of thing in your view?

Comment: No I did not insert any debugger. index.html.erb is all I have in the view.

Comment: Please check something might be generating from your layout...As the footer is also seen....Please check your layout file...

Comment: `<%= @users.each do |user|  %>` remove `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @users.each do |user|  %>
```

Should be like

```
<% @users.each do |user|  %>
```